# postback error when using linkbutton PostBackUrl with query string

Tags: c#, asp.net

My page is `someName.aspx`. I have one link button

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnCase1" runat="server" PostBackUrl="someName.aspx?caseNo=1" OnClick="lnkBtnCase1_Click">Case1</asp:LinkButton>
```

The postback address is to the same page ie. `someName.aspx`. But when I click the link button this error shows up:

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

How can I postback to the same page and get the query string value on clicking the link button. I have a repeater control in the page which is filled according to the value of query string.

Answer (score 0):

Try to having `enableEventValidation="false"`

Answer (score 0):

If you are posting to the same page you don't need to set the PostBackUrl, it is for posting to a different page. Instead you should add a property in the page that contains the caseNo-variable. Either some kind of control (textbox etc) or a hidden property. Then the CaseId will be available in the query string in your ASP.NET code.